# PS1 Start-Process script error - Cant run document in the middle of pipeline

Tags: powershell

I Have 1 PowerShell script in .psm1 form so I can have a custom cmdlet. The thing is, I had no idea what I was doing so I just found an article. I copied the article and the only change I made was to change the cmdlet function to "Start-Process". I also made it start WT.exe (Windows Terminal) and added arguments that work perfectly in a normal ps1 file.

**My Code:**

```
    Function txtedit
    {
        Start-Process -FilePath 'wt.exe' -ArgumentList "-NoExit python C:\Users\hjdom\OneDrive\Documents\pyUtils\texteditor\main.py"
    }

Export-ModuleMember -Function 'txtedit'
```

**The error PowerShell returned:**

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\txtedit> c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\txtedit\txtedit.psm1
Cannot run a document in the middle of a pipeline: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\txtedit\txtedit.psm1.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (C:\Windows\Syst...it\txtedit.psm1:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantActivateDocumentInPipeline
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does it make a difference if you specify the full path for the windows terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Terminal (wt.exe) is not a command shell.

It is a host for command shells (powershell, bash, cmd, python, perl, etc.). You have to tell WT.exe which to use, to call your script.

Example - cmd.exe or via the WinKey Run:

Type:

```
wt d:\temp\hello.ps1
```

this will fail with...

```
[error 0x800700c1 when launching `d:\temp\hello.ps1']
```

... even though Windows Terminal launches with whatever default shell is in your WT settings.

Now do this...

```
wt.exe powershell D:\Scripts\hello.ps1
```

... this works, because you told wt.exe which shell to use to execute your script.

> but then how do I prevent the terminal from closing after the script
> is done running?

Your target shell needs to provide a method for that. Powershell (Windows and Core) provide this via the `-NoExit` switch.

```
powershell /?

PowerShell[.exe] [-PSConsoleFile <file> | -Version <version>]
    [-NoLogo] [-NoExit] [-Sta] [-Mta] [-NoProfile] [-NonInteractive]
    [-InputFormat {Text | XML}] [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}]
    [-WindowStyle <style>] [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]
    [-ConfigurationName <string>]
    [-File <filePath> <args>] [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>]
    [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]
                  | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]

wt.exe powershell -NoProfile -NoLogo -NoExit D:\Scripts\hello.ps1

wt.exe pwsh -NoProfile -NoLogo -NoExit D:\Scripts\hello.ps1
```

If you are calling another shell, bash, python, perl, etc., then they too would need to provide that.